# Cannot drop a table in SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql, tsql

I have a SQL Server 2005 SP3 box that one of my developers created a temp table on that we cannot seem to remove because it somehow got brackets in the name of the table?

```
SELECT Name, object_id FROM sys.objects WHERE Name LIKE '%#example%'
Results:
Name        object_id
[#example]  123828384
```

Anyone know how we can get rid of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe table wasn't showing up in SMS 2005, so I used SMS 2008 and ran as Administrator, and then I was able to remove the table via the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the whole name with square brackets.

e.g.

```
drop table [[#example]
```

Should do it I think

Comment: That's what I tried first and it just returned a syntax error with "unclosed quotation mark after string"